# NPEs with JavaFX's HTMLEditor

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I wrote a relatively simple test class:

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override public void start(Stage stage) {
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);

        HTMLEditor editor = new HTMLEditor();
        root.setCenter(editor);

        Platform.runLater(editor::requestFocus);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

If I run this (the editor has focus), I am greeted by this rather bleak looking window, and if I type anything, I immediately get a `NullPointerException`:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.web.skin.HTMLEditorSkin.applyTextFormatting(HTMLEditorSkin.java:1100)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.web.skin.HTMLEditorSkin.lambda$new$3(HTMLEditorSkin.java:293)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
...
```

[image]

The three things I noticed at first were:

1. The error seems to be related to `HTMLEditorSkin`, so I tried applying one but Eclipse informs me this class is not API. How can I use this (if I should) and if yes, should I make an access restriction (since JavaFX itself is not API either)?
2. The `HTMLEditor` looks unfocused, **and has no selected font by default** (I think this is where the problem is being caused.)
3. The `HTMLEditorSkin` is from the package hierarchy `com.sun.javafx` and not `javafx`.

However, it seems that I am doing everything correctly according to the [first example of Oracle's tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/editor.htm).

What is going wrong here? It feels like this may be a bug.

---

Attempted solutions and already-received answers:

1. Setting initial text with `setHtmlText`.
   `setHtmlText("<body style='font-family: something;'>text</body>");`
   It does set the text and a font but the editor is unaffected.
2. Set style with `setStyle`.
   `setStyle("-fx-font: 12 something");`
   This only changes the UI font.
3. Installing JDK 8u122.

Comment: It's a bug which occurs in some environments (mostly in Linux I think). Upgrade to JDK 8u122 and the bug is gone.

Comment: @Omid I am using Windows, but I will try once I am back at my PC. edit: seems this is an early access build - has this just been fixed?

Comment: Yes, it's an early access build. I don't know if it is fixed in 8u121 (current) but I try to check it as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is raised because due to a bug, `HtmlEditor` does not set a font family by default and when you start typing there are no fonts selected so you'll get `NPE`. Notice that if you select a font family before starting to type, no error is raised.

In order to avoid this bug upgrade to [JDK 8u122](https://jdk8.java.net/download.html). (Tested on `Kubuntu 16.10` with `jre-8u122-ea-bin-b04-linux-x64-25_oct_2016`)

P.S. I did not check previous versions. This could have been fixed in earlier releases but it exists in `8u111`.

Comment: I have tried this (and uninstalled old JDKs) and at least for me nothing seems to have changed. Edit: seems to work on Mac even without updating. Perhaps it's a Windows-related bug?

Comment: I use Kubuntu 16.10 and I had this problem with jdk 8u111 and when I changed to jre 8u122 (ea) it was gone. No clue why it's not working on Windows though.

Comment: It works on another Windows laptop I have access to. No idea what is going on, but thanks for your suggestions

Comment: Accepting this answer because it fixed it in your case. Reinstalling Windows worked for me, however.

Comment: It's strange :) Anyway I'm glad your problem is solved.